# Handling COM DLLs with different signatures in C#

Tags: c#, com, signature

I'm working with a COM DLL that annoyling has changed one of it's method signatures from `Foo(ref ushort bar)` to `Foo(ref short bar)` depending on whatever version the user has installed.

Performance is crucial, but I can't think of any solution that doesn't involve reflection. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If you can edit the DLL to use only one of boh signatures, you can reinterpret-cast between ``ushort`` and ``short`` with ``unchecked { ... }``

Comment: Ideas to do what? i.e. what is the problem? if you have one interop dll for the first version, can't you just reuse it also for the second one (i.e. it should not crash, since the size of the data is the same)?

Answer (score 2):

The DLL broke the COM tenet of [interface immutability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688484(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **COM interfaces are immutable**. You cannot define a new version of an old interface and give it the same identifier. Adding or removing methods of an interface or changing semantics creates a new interface, not a new version of an old interface. Therefore, a new interface cannot conflict with an old interface. However, objects can support multiple interfaces simultaneously and can expose interfaces that are successive revisions of an interface, with different identifiers. Thus, each interface is a separate contract, and system wide objects need not be concerned about whether the version of the interface they are calling is the one they expect. The interface ID (IID) defines the interface contract explicitly and uniquely.

This is not 'annoying'. This is *broken*. The DLL author must define a *new* interface, with the new signature.